# Not work d3.select.attr(filter) with SMART TV Samsung ME40c

Tags: javascript, d3.js, smart-tv

I have a web app which dynamically updates HTML every 5 sec. When I am using filter for svg files it doesn't work in TV Browser, but with PC works fine

my function:

```
function addEfect(el_id, ef_id, opasite) {

    if (typeof(opasite) === 'undefined') {
        opasite = 1;
    }

    d3.select('#' + el_id).attr('filter','url(#' + ef_id + ')');
    d3.select('#' + el_id).style('opacity', opasite);
}
```

included in index.html

```
   <script language='javascript' src='<?php echo base_url();?         >javascripts/d3.js'></script>
   <script language='javascript' src='<?php echo base_url();?>javascripts/jquery-ui.js'></script>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo base_url();?>css/page.css'>
```

Anyone please help me, who knows what i do wrong!

for example hide filter:

```
    var h_filter = svg.select('defs')
   .append('filter')            .attr('id','h_filter')
   .append('feComponentTransfer');

   h_filter.append('feFuncR')
   .attr('type','identity');

   h_filter.append('feFuncG')
   .attr('type','identity');

   h_filter.append('feFuncB')
   .attr('type','identity');

   h_filter.append('feFuncA')
   .attr('type','linear')
   .attr('slope','0')
   .attr('intercept','0');
```

In browser FireFox works fine

Comment: This Smart tv's browser doesn't work with js filters((! Only way is to replace pics with different collors